Promote Dogtag PKI replica to be the new master
We are trying to promote our Dogtag PKI replica server to be the new master and then decommission the old master. I was able to find some documentation for the IPA process to do this but haven't been able to find anything yet that is specific to Dogtag.
In our CS.cfg on the replica we have this:
master.ca.agent.host=master.server.example.com
master.ca.agent.port=8443

Would it be as simple as removing those two lines from the CS.cfg on the replica, maybe set this line to true as well:
ca.crl.MasterCRL.enableCRLUpdates=false

and restart pki-tomcat and the dirsrv services?
Any insight provided or links to appropriate Dogtag docs that I seem to be unable to find would be much appreciated.
